# Writing to CSV and content overflowing cells

Tags: xml, perl, csv

Within Perl, I'm trying to parse and XML and write the contents to a CSV file. Some of the text I'm extracting from the XML is huge - paragraphs actually. This when I write to the CSV file, is very understandbly, messing the cells up. The content is spilling into other cells and pushing the data out.

I tried to look for a "column-wrap" option prior to writing it, but there is none which obviously is not a CSV function.

Below is the code which I am using. I'm concatenating the elements of the array into a string and writing this humongous string to CSV file. 
    #------Output file handling----------#
    open (OutFile,">>$design_extract") or die "$!";
    print OutFile "Design,Control Type,Study_Purpose,Primary Objectives\n";

```
$study_content = join(" ", @study_arr), "\n";
print OutFile "$design_id,$control_type,$study_content,$prime_obj_content\n";
```

Both study content and primary objectives are very long strings.@study_arr is an array of strings(lines of text) extracted from the XML file.

Anyone has any better ideas on how I can write this huge data to a CSV and still make it look readable and pretty?Any input is greatly appreciated.

TIA,Simak

Answer (score 3):

- *“Some of the text I'm extracting from the XML is huge - paragraphs actually.”* — doesn't matter, It's not like there would be a max line length.
- *“When I write to the CSV file, [this is] messing the cells up.”* — CSV has no concept of “cells”. A CSV file is not a MS Excel/LO Calc spreadsheet. It is just a format to represent tabular data as a plain text file.
- *“I tried to look for a "column-wrap" option”* — Again, CSV has no representational markup. It is just tabular data.
- “`print OutFile "$foo,$bar,$baz\n";`” — This is the source of some of your problems: You don't handle possible commata inside your fields properly. The usual way to mitigate this is to enclose the field in quotes. Example:

  ```
  Work,Author,Quote
  Hamlet,"William Shakespeare","To be, or not to be, that is the question"
  ```

  Simply interpolating variables doesn't account for newlines either, which are often used as record separators.
- *“how I can write this huge data to a CSV and still make it look readable and pretty?”* — Write your data to a CSV file, and create another file that is extra pretty. You can create nice tables with HTML/CSS or LaTeX.

  If you want it as plain text, Perl's `format`/`write` builtins could help, as a column can stretch multiple lines. However, I perceive them as antiquated, and would rather advocate the other possibilities.

#### How to properly write a CSV file

Simple: `use Text::CSV`. Don't reinvent the wheel.

```
use strict; use warnings; use autodie;
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ binary => 1, eol => $/ });
open my $fh, ">:utf8", "some file";

my @rows = (
  [qw/ Work Author Quote /],
  ["Hamlet", "William Shakespeare", "To be, or not to be, that is the question"],
);

for my $row (@rows) {
  $csv->print($fh, $row);
}
```

Output as in the above example.